# Count active accounts per month over a year in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Snowflake to try to figure out a way to count the number of active clients per month over a set period i.e. last 12 months.

The code I have only counts the total number of active clients over the whole year, what i need to see is if client A is active in Jan and Feb but not in Mar but active again in Apr then my current code would show that this client is active, ignoring the fact that they werent active in Mar.

I want this broken down by month and year and grouped by month and a count of active clients per month.

My current code looks like this:

```sql
SELECT
    A.account_billing_country,
    Count (distinct a.acc_id) as active_clients
FROM
    Payments p
INNER JOIN accounts a
    ON a.acc_id = p.acc_id
WHERE date(transfered_at) >= dateadd(year,-1, current date)
GROUP BY 1
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please update your question with some sample data (enough to cover all your use cases) and the result you want to achieve based on that sample data

Comment: How did you define "active"?Does user log in Jan2022 and again back in Jan2023 is it still active?Get some sample data which could help us to drive .

Answer (score 1):

This query looks at active Stack Overflow users asking questions for each tag, looking at the whole year for previous activity to count the # of actives reported for each month:

```sql
select tag, report_date, count(distinct q_owner) one_year_actives
from so_qa_tag
join (select distinct date_trunc(month, q_date) report_date from so_qa_tag)
where q_date between dateadd(year, -1, report_date) and report_date
and report_date > '2012-01-01'
and tag in('java', 'javascript', 'python', 'c#', 'sql')
group by tag, report_date
order by tag, report_date
```

[image]

The secret is to do a join with a list of months (`report_date`), and look at all activity in the table within a year before that date (`q_date between dateadd(year, -1, report_date) and report_date`).

Comment: Thanks Felipe. So i basically have a "created_date" that is from the payments table and the definition of a client being active is having a date in the "created_date" field. I am joining the accounts table to the payments table in order to obtain the account name and the payment created date field. My code looks as above (although i have added country code aswell). Im not used to using Snowflake but the expected results would be a list of months, a count of acc ids that have a "created_date" within each of the months. So as an example, Jan 100 active clients, Feb 102 active clients etc

Comment: I think you should start a new question making it clear how your data looks and how the results should look